# Building a specific crate doesn't reuse artifacts from full workspace build

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I use cargo workspaces with projects in it. When I'm running

```
cargo build
```

from workspaces root dir it builds all project members (correct me if I'm wrong).

Then when I want to build a particular project from the workspace I use

```
cargo build -p my_project_1
```

And it looks like it starts to build my_project_1 dependencies. Despite the fact that all dependencies supposed to be build on the  first  `cargo build`  stage.

How to use dependencies build cache done on the first stage?

Comment: It does reuse build artifacts for me, are theer any dependencies which would be built with different flags for only that one package vs the whole workspace?

Comment: Also only `default-members` are build if you have that key in the workspace `Cargo.toml`

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] ie some combination of `Cargo.toml`s and sources which don't reuse build artifacts?

Comment: Here's one reproducible example: https://github.com/PRQL/prql/issues/3098 (though hardly a minimal one...)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [a recent cargo update has addressed this](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4890), and `cargo build` should now produce an error message like this:

```
error: failed to compile `doomed-to-fail v0.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at '/some/tmp/directory'
    To reuse those artifacts, set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to that path.
```

Even with an older version of cargo which *doesn't* print the extra-helpful error message, you can still set `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to re-use the existing artifacts. I can confirm that this works with cargo 1.70.0 (on a macOS system using MacPorts):

```bash
CARGO_TARGET_DIR=/var/folders/fp/abc…xyz/T/cargo-installABC123 cargo install git-hist
```

The 91 dependencies that came before the actual failure were *not* re-built, as expected.